# AWS S3, Paperclip missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use Paperclip and SWS S3 on Heroku to let users upload images.

I do not have my credentials stored in a yml file. I've followed the instructions on the Heroku page:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

But, when I try to run my app and upload an image I'm getting this message:

```
missing required :bucket option
Rails.root: /Users/scottsipiora/Sites/clycss

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/instructors_controller.rb:63:in `block in update'
app/controllers/instructors_controller.rb:62:in `update'
```

The instructions don't mention anything about making a change in my controller. I have seen some examples telling me to put in something like:

In my model I have the following code:

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bio, :hometown, :name, :school, :sort_order, :started_sailing, :started_teaching, :photo
  has_attached_file :photo, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }
end
```

In my production.rb I have (obviously replacing my real credentials with mock credentials):

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['bucket name'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['key_id'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['access_key']
    }
  }
```

I've also created separate buckets for Production and Dev so things are cleaner.

Any ideas? I'm relatively new and this should be pretty easy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

I think you may have made the same mistake I did.  In your production.rb file, do not edit the text to add your specific S3 keys.  Just copy-paste the text directly as is listed in the tutorial.

```
#production.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Then, set the environmental variables AWS_BUCKET, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  as described by the author of the dev center article.

Answer (score 10):

Do `heroku config` to check your environment variables.

Normally they are all caps and have underbars instead of spaces.

If it is not set, you should set the environment variable with

```
heroku config:add BUCKET_NAME=my_bucket_name
```

Update your code:

```
:bucket => ENV['BUCKET_NAME'],
```

[Heroku reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Comment: Heroku logs are showing ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):

Comment: Heroku logs are also showing: app/controllers/instructors_controller.rb:63:in `block in update' and pp/controllers/instructors_controller.rb:62:in `update'. What am I supposed to put in my controller?

Comment: This helped me. I forgot to set my ENV property for the bucket.

Answer (score 7):

Scott, sorry if there was any confusion here.

I am the author of the Dev Center article. As B Seven stated above the AWS Config Vars need to be set on the Heroku application.

Heroku has recently updated their documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#example) and `set` is preferred over `add` going forward.

```
$ heroku config:set AWS_BUCKET=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
```

Comment: I have same issue on localhost. Already added configuration to development file with my amazon config. What can be wrong? Why :bucket option can be missed? It is because of missed config?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you restart your CLI of choice when setting values with environment variables. Don't be like me and set up Paperclip and AWS correctly with ENV variables and then waste a bunch of time on Google only to fix the issue by quitting and reopening Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

- Insert into schema.rb table "instructors" this line

> ```
> create_table "instructors" do |t|
>     ...
>     t.string   "bucket"
> end
> ```

- Add to controller `@instructor[:bucket] = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']`
- Run "rake db:setup"