# ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I am following the One Month Rails course, and I am stuck at uploading image to the AWS server via Heroku. My Github Folder: https://github.com/phanatuan/pinteresting

The error in the Heroku log is:

```
"ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:30:in `create' "
```

I understand that this is the error many people get. However, hard as I search throught other Stackoverflow questions and answers, I could not find the solutions.

Thank you very much for your help

Tuan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444264/aws-s3-paperclip-missing-required-bucket-option

Comment: I did come across that above question but the solution does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently taking the OneMonth Rails tutorial and this was a big headache for me too!

Instead of following what OMRails tells you, which is:

```
$ heroku config:set AWS_BUCKET=BUCKET_NAME_VALUE
```

Use this instead:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=BUCKET_NAME_VALUE
```

And then wrap it up with:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ git push heroku master
```

If you have already set your 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' and your 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' there is no need to repeat or change those.

The final code should look like this:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly defining the bucket in your association `has_attached_file`

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, 
            :style => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
            :storage => :s3,
            :bucket  => ENV['MY_BUCKET_NAME']
    validates :image, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
end
```

And even more explicitly , define all your configs inline

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, 
            :style => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
            :storage => :s3,
            :bucket  => ENV['MY_BUCKET_NAME'],
            :s3_credentials => {
                    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                },
                :s3_permissions => 'private',
                :url => ":s3_domain_url"
    validates :image, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
end
```

I'm using ENV vars in this example but you can obviously hardcode your config values. Start from there and then work your way back to placing configs into an initializer.

Comment: Just don't add a config file with secret keys and passwords to your version control.  I use the dotenv gem to add environment variables painlessly during development.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and it was fixed by running:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=BUCKET_NAME_VALUE
```

make sure you have the name set to "S3" in your production.rb file:

```
# Sets Paperclip to upload images to Amazon S3
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

I had a real headache with this, too.

Do the above, then add and commit and push to git, then run

```
git push heroku master
```

Then you will hopefully be good to go. I don't think you need to do

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

in this case, but I might be wrong. I'm a newbie too!